# How to mass assign subunit in OrangeHRM

Tags: mysql, orangehrm

Is there a way to mass assign a sub-unit in OrangeHRM?
I have looked into the MySQl tables for employees and subunits but there seems to be no common id between the two.

We are trying to edit a mass uploaded employee list of around 400 and doing it individually is going to be a pain in the *(&^. :)

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be very much appreciated. :)
TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVM. I found the answer. For those who are having the same problem (though I doubt someone is) :) the sub-unit for each employee is under the work_station column in hs_hr_employee table. The number indicates the id of the corresponding unit under the ohrm_subunit table.

Did the mass assignment usign mySQL queries.

Comment: I appreciate your effort to close your own question with an answer. Please mark this answer as accepted to show that it is resolved...